# How to convert a Series of arrays into a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there a way to convert a Pandas Series where each row contains an array into a 2D numpy array?

The Series looks like the following below when you display it in Python:

```
[array([ 58.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.])
 array([ 77.,  95.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.])]
```

I would like to get a numpy matrix that looks like this:

```
[[ 58.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.]
 [ 77.,  95.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.]]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([np.array([ 58.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.]),
               np.array([ 77.,  95.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.])])      

rslt = np.array(s.tolist())


rslt
Out[16]: 
array([[ 58.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.],
       [ 77.,  95.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If:

```
s = pd.Series([np.array([ 58.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.]),
               np.array([ 77.,  95.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.])])
```

Then

```
s.apply(pd.Series).values
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [pd.Series([np.array([ 77.,  95.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.]),np.array([ 58.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.,  -1.])])]
```